# VBA Code to format text copied over from Excel to PowerpoInt

Tags: vba, excel, powerpoint

I'm having trouble figuring out how to format text after I have pasted it to PowerPoint from Excel.  My code correctly copies over text but i can't seem to format it properly. I'm copying over multiple columns of text into each slide under each dept title. I have included a loop because I will be doing this for multiple slides for each manager. However, I don't know how to position the columns on the slide after i paste them. I would appreciate any help or suggestions on what I should do?

```
Sub CreateNewPresentation()

Dim myData As Excel.Range
Set myData = Range("D3:E1000")

Dim ppApp As PowerPoint.Application
Dim ppPres As PowerPoint.Presentation
Dim ppSlide As PowerPoint.Slide

Set ppApp = New PowerPoint.Application

ppApp.Visible = True
ppApp.Activate

Set ppPres = ppApp.Presentations.Add

Set ppSlide = ppPres.Slides.Add(1, ppLayoutTitle)

ppSlide.Shapes(1).TextFrame.TextRange = "Title of Powerpoint"
ppSlide.Shapes(2).TextFrame.TextRange = "Author"

Set ppSlide = ppPres.Slides.Add(2, ppLayoutCustom)

ppSlide.Shapes(1).TextFrame.TextRange = "Manager Name"

Set tbox1 = ppSlide.Shapes.AddTextbox(msoTextOrientationHorizontal, 100, 125, 75, 50)
tbox1.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "Dept 1"
tbox1.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Bold = msoTrue
tbox1.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 150, 0)

Set tbox2 = ppSlide.Shapes.AddTextbox(msoTextOrientationHorizontal, 300, 125, 75, 50)
tbox2.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "Dept 2"
tbox2.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Bold = msoTrue
tbox2.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 150, 0)

Set tbox3 = ppSlide.Shapes.AddTextbox(msoTextOrientationHorizontal, 500, 125, 75, 50)
tbox3.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "Dept 3"
tbox3.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Bold = msoTrue
tbox3.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 150, 0)

Set tbox1 = ppSlide.Shapes.AddTextbox(msoTextOrientationHorizontal, 700, 125, 80, 50)
tbox1.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "Dept 4"
tbox1.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Bold = msoTrue
tbox1.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 150, 0)

Dim prerow As Integer
prerow = 3

Dim nextrow As Integer
Range("D3").Select

Dim SlideNo As Integer

SlideNo = 2
Do While True

Selection.End(xlDown).Select
If Selection.Value = "" Then

  Exit Do
  End If

nextrow = Selection.Row
Range("E" & prerow & ":E" & nextrow - 1).Select
    Selection.Copy

  ppPres.Slides(SlideNo).Shapes.Paste

   If Range("E" & nextrow).Offset(-1, 0) = "" Then
    SlideNo = SlideNo + 1
    nextrow = nextrow + 1
    End If

   prerow = nextrow
   Range("D" & prerow).Select

   Loop

   End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Very difficult to follow all what your code is actually achieving and I had trouble testing it.. But concerning the main question:

> how to position the columns on the slide after i paste them

You can get a handle to the shape you just pasted and set its `.Top` and `.Left` properties. For example, when you paste a column,

> ```
> ppPres.Slides(SlideNo).Shapes.Paste
> ```

You can use indtead

```
 With ppPres.Slides(SlideNo).Shapes.Paste
   .Top = tbox1.Top + tbox1.Width + 5
   .Left = tbox1.Left
 End With
```

This will place a pasted column under `tbox1`... Write your loop in such a way that each pasted column falls at the appropriate place.